# How to find out which objects share the same color?

Tags: materials, objects, color

I have created a scene with a lot of objects and I'd like to clean up the project. My question is: how can I find out which objects share the same color?

[image]

There are 2 objects that share the same color, 1 object is the cube but where is the second Object?

Comment: Do you want to know which objects use the same *Material*, as shown in the screenshot, or which objects have the same *color* assigned to, e.g. the *Principled BSDF*?

Comment: Hi @Robert-Gützkow, I will know who Object share the color! I cant find the second Object

Comment: You can use the outliner and search for the material name in the display filter.

Comment: The indicator for the number of users, as marked with red in your screenshot, is for the users of a *material*, in this case for the material *testfarbe*. Please select one object with the material and then try *Select > Select Linked > Material*. Does that give you the desired result?

Comment: negativ :-/ I dont see it

Answer (score 5):

You can use the outliner to filter the scene collection by name.

So you can use it in order to search using the material name.

Once done select all the filtered objects using <kbd>A</kbd> in the outliner.

[image]

Comment: yeahhhhhh :-) thank a lot :-)!!!!!!
I wish you a creative day !!!!!

Comment: Consider to accept the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour @73district

Comment: That's an even better approach when you want to know the object's name.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then press <kbd>T</kbd>, click on materials and check the screen where all objects are listed and find which object is also selected (while being in *Object Mode*).

Comment: :-/ I press crtl+L and choose material but I don´t see it !!!

Comment: I think the answer is good but this is Shift+L for me.